# Users can't get to my web site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a new web site I created inside a corporate network. All my users are in the same AD domain (WINNTDOM) and the same LAN. I am an admin on the server (MTVFA-FINANCE MS Server 2008 IIS 7.0), and I deployed the web site using VS2010 web deploy. From my client, I am able to get to the web site with no problem (http: //mtvfac-finance/Timesheets), and everything works fine. My web.config allows all non-anonamous users. IIS for the site is set to allow Windows Authentication (only). All of my users are AD users.

When my users try to go to that same link, they all get an HTTP:400 error. Where do I look for the problem? Is there a log somewhere that can give me more information?

Answer (score 0):

My Client's tech support group did some work on this and found:

> When I tried with my regular user account using IE, I got an HTTP 400 error.  If I tried using my domain admin account using IE, it worked – well I got your “you are not authorized…”  rejected.aspx page showing up. Interestingly, Firefox did not have the problem…and IE didn’t seem to either if I used the IP address rather than the hostname “xxxxxx-yyyyyyy” in the url.  So at first I thought it was something to do with the “-“ in the hostname.  But researching an HTTP 400 error, it points to users being in too many groups when using Windows Authentication.  The suggested solution to get around the issue is to increase the value of two HTTP settings in the registry on the server.  I did that, restarted HTTP, and now my account that was failing before with the HTTP 400 error is now getting the same “you are not authorized…” message from your rejected.aspx page.
>   So it wasn’t that your admin account and mine were working…it’s just that those two accounts aren’t members of too many groups while your test user apparently is and my regular account is as well.So it wasn’t that your admin account and mine were working…it’s just that those two accounts aren’t members of too many groups while your test user apparently is and my regular account is as well.

Seems to have worked....